# Store value of ConfigurableDirectory in registry

Tags: wix, wix3

Our installer allows the users to select where they want to install certain files, but we need to have a registry entry that points to that location.  I am using the ConfigurableDirectory option of the Feature to do that.  How can I get the directory that the user selected so I can write it to the registry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I missed that "bracketed names will be looked up and if found, replaced with their actual value." in the [Wix tutorial](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson1.php#1.5)

So I was able to do the following.

```
    <Component Id="DataFileRegEntry" Guid="" >
      <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="keypath" >
        <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Calibration" Value="[FILES]"  />
      </RegistryKey>
    </Component>
```